# How to bind uploaded file to form object property?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I would like to have the form object like this:

```
public class FormData {

    private MultipartFile file1;

    private MultipartFile file2;

    // setters/getters for above fields and other properties
}
```

and I would like SpringMVC to bind e.g. `<input type="file" name="file1">` HTML form field to my form object property. I haven't found any JSP tag for that (like `<form:file path="file1" />` or `<form:input type="file" path="file1" />`) in `spring-form.tld`. Is it possible at all? If not, is this limitation rooted too deep in Spring internals and cannot be easily overcome?

I know how to bind file upload form value to controller method argument (described in [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart)):

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView compare(@ModelAttribute(FORM_BEAN_NAME) FormData formData,
    @RequestParam("file1") MultipartFile file1,
    @RequestParam("file2") MultipartFile file2,
    BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

but I would be happier if all HTML form elements are bound to one class and method signature does not boost when new upload fields are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly this a couple of years ago. The only difference I can remember is I used `CommonsMultipartFile` instead of an interface. What happens if you try this, it throws an exception or simply values don't get bound?

Comment: Why haven't you used `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` interface for that which is more generic?

Comment: I don't remember the reason, maybe it doesn't has sense. Have you tried it? What happens?

Comment: Thanks, it looks that binding